# How to play just the audio of YouTube Video?

Tags: ios, ios6, youtube-api, gdata

In my app I have played a youtube video by embedding it, but how can i only play the audio of the video? I tried using AVAudioPlayer and use the videos url as the file path but it didnt work, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible, only one workaround is just to use a hidden `UIWebView` and play in that.

Youtube forbids playing audio only! here is the message from youtube

> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to:  "separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API"
>    -Kuan Yong, YouTube API Team

Comment: is there api changed ? I want to play audio songs from youtube in iOS